# Why did Russia, Cuba, NK, China support the Peruvian government during the internal conflict?

Tags: war, communism, south-america, latin-america

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_conflict_in_Peru) has me scratching my head at the righthand information panel especially at the information under "Belligerents". According to the list China, North Korea, Cuba, Russia (Soviet Union) all support(ed) the Peruvian government during what's known as the internal conflict in Peru. Why do they do that?

I think a big part of the conflict, the most significant, high-activity phase, took place during Alberto Fujimori's reign, a hardcore conservative anti-communist right-winger, socially, militarily, and economically. So I don't see any reasons that he might have aligned himself with Soviet Union/Russia, Cuba and China, or would have won their support. His nemesis [the Shining Path (Communist Party of Peru)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shining_Path), on the other hand, is a Marxist-Leninist-Maoist group, so it seems  only reasonable that they, as opposed to Fujimori, should have in their corner China, NK, Cuba, Russia etc.

There isn't much information I can find on that page or on other related pages. Why did China, Cuba, and Russia throw their weight behind the Peruvian government especially Fujimori?

Comment: Any idea what is meant by "support" here? E.g. lots of countries have made statements about their support for the one-China principle while in practice they are doing nothing (less than nothing in some cases).

Comment: Other question: Supporting those terrorists might mean that Russia etc. would possibly lose access to Peruvian markets and all trust and credibility within Peruvian politics. For what benefit exactly?

Comment: Third question: Were Shining Path and those countries really compatible politically, or was it more like Iran and the IS (both Islamist) or Taliban and ISKP (both Sunni Islamist)? Are you aware that China and the Soviet Union were almost at war in the late 1960s?

Comment: The Shining Path weren't your garden variety communists. Communist nations were about as likely to embrace Shining Path as Scientologists were to embrace Charles Manson, and for [roughly the same reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Lucanamarca_massacre).

Answer (score 2):

> According to the list China, North Korea, Cuba, Russia (Soviet Union) all support(ed) the Peruvian government during what's known as the internal conflict in Peru. Why do they do that?

Looks to me as a formatting error of the list, where some of the countries have been misplaced (China, Cuba, North Korea, Soviet Union/Russia).

This should be reported to Wikipedia directly so that they can correct it.

The chapters

- Background

  - National Liberation Army (ELN) led by Juan Pablo Chang Navarro and trained by Cuba.
- The Shining Path

  - the Shining Path had been organized as a Maoist political group formed in 1970 by Abimael Guzmán, a communist professor of philosophy at the San Cristóbal of Huamanga University. Guzmán had been inspired by the Chinese Cultural Revolution which he had witnessed first-hand during a trip to China

directly name some countries that did not support the government side.

---

> Comment from [justCal](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/16951/justcal):
> **Why does this wikipedia page say Russia, the Soviet Union, China and Cuba support the Govt of Peru?** Because one person edited the page on 16 June to say so...The information being discussed was recently added to the wiki page in [16 June 2023](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Internal_conflict_in_Peru&action=history). The individual has made more than 30 edits to the page in the last 30 days...

Comment: Did you check the supporting references (El Pais) to the claims that you are attempting to refute? I can use a logic similar to yours to argue that France supported the HRE during the 30 year war.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Just because China 'rejects and condemns the violence practiced by the Maoist groups' doesn't mean it **supports** the right wing government of Peru (a **very wierd** conclusion). As stated in the answer, this is a matter that should brought to the attention of the Wikipedia authors directly since the listing contradicts what is written in the body of the text.

Comment: **Why does this wikipedia page say Russia, the Soviet Union, China and Cuba support the Govt of Peru?** Because one person edited the page on 16 June to say so...The information being discussed was recently added to the wiki page in [16 June 2023](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Internal_conflict_in_Peru&action=history). The individual has made more than 30 edits to the page in the last 30 days...